# select varchar as date in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a date column in the format

> 25 Mar 2017 07:19 pm

I want to select date in the format dd/mm/yyyy

I have tried: `cast(date as DATE), STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y')` but everything returns null

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you're early in your project, you should immediately ALTER your column to be a  `DATETIME` type; it will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: It's a transition project and I am new to php world, but I know your suggestion is worth pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
select str_to_date('25 Mar 2017 07:19 pm', '%d %M %Y')
```

The format specified has to match the input pattern. As the month name is included, use `%M`.

Comment: This ignores time and returns date with 00:00:00 time.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the date using following format:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('25 Mar 2017 07:19 pm', '%d %M %Y %h:%i %p');
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9167e/12/0)**.